# Critical Points of System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system below

> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = -y + xg(x,y)$$
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dt} = x + yg(x,y)$$

Is there any condition that must be satisfied in order fot the origin to be an isolated critical point. The only thing I can think of is that if $-y^2g(x,y) - x^2g(x,y) \neq 0$ (ie $ad - bc \neq 0$) then the origin is an isolated critical point, but this doesn't work because we can let $x$ and $y$ be zero which would cause $ad -bc = 0$. Is there any other way to show that the origin is an isolated critical point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by critical point you mean a point $(x,y)$ such that $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, then any critical point $(x,y)$ will satisfy $$0=-y+xg(x,y)\\0=x+yg(x,y),$$ or equivalently $$y=xg(x,y)\\0=x+yg(x,y).$$ By substitution, $$0=x\bigl(1+g(x,y)^2),$$ so $x=0$, whence back-substitution yields $y=0$. Hence, the only possible critical point is $(0,0)$. This is indeed a critical point, so it is the only one, and so is isolated.